# Postgresql: How to join to table not referenced in from clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I've got a postgres database in which I occasionally run the following query:

```
UPDATE b_address ba
SET op_id = op.land_id
FROM openb op
WHERE ba.str = op.name
AND (ba.openb_id IS NULL OR ba.openb_id = '');
```

This works, but I now only want to do this for the records in the table `b_address` where the `source` equals `"E"`. The source however, is stored in another table called `b_b`, which I can join on `b_address` like this:

```
SELECT ba.id, bb.source
FROM b_address ba
JOIN b_b bb ON bb.id = ba.bb_id
WHERE bb.source = 'E';
```

I'm now struggeling to add this join to the UPDATE query so that I only update records from b_address which have a `source = 'E'`.

I tried this:

```
UPDATE b_address ba
SET op_id = op.land_id
FROM openb op
JOIN b_b bb ON bb.id = ba.bb_id
WHERE bb.source = 'E'
AND ba.str = op.name
AND (ba.openb_id IS NULL OR ba.openb_id = '');
```

But I then get this:

```
ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "ba"
  Hint: There is an entry for table "ba", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

That makes sense, because a table is always joined to the table in the `FROM` clause. I'm unsure how I would fit these together though.

Any tips on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . One method is a `cross join`:

```
UPDATE b_address ba
    SET op_id = op.land_id
    FROM openb op CROSS JOIN
         b_b bb 
    WHERE bb.id = ba.bb_id AND
          bb.source = 'E' AND
          ba.str = op.name AND
          (ba.openb_id IS NULL OR ba.openb_id = '');
```

An alternative is a subquery:

```
UPDATE b_address ba
    SET op_id = op.land_id
    FROM openb op
    WHERE ba.str = op.name AND
          (ba.openb_id IS NULL OR ba.openb_id = '') AND
          EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b_b bb WHERE bb.id = ba.bb_id AND bb.source = 'E');
```

I actually prefer this structure over the first one.